# Por que não consigo usar $window.localStorage.setItem() com angular?

Tags: angularjs

Após o cadastro, estou querendo colocar, temporariamente, alguns dados em localStorage, mas não estou conseguindo.

Segue meu código:

```
app.controller('cadastroCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$cordovaSQLite', '$window', '$state', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $cordovaSQLite, $window, $state) {

$scope.email = [];

$scope.cadastrar = function(usuario){

$http.post("http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/serviapp/api_gustavo/register.php", usuario).success(function(response){

    var nome = response.nome;
    var email = response.email;
    var id = response.idusuario;
    var is_professional = response.prof;

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){    

        if(is_professional == 1){
            $window.localStorage.setItem('userPro', nome);
            $scope.email = $window.localStorage.setItem('emailPro', email);
            $window.localStorage.setItem('idPro', id);

            console.log('Profissional');

            $state.go('menuProfissional');
        }else{
            $window.localStorage.setItem('userCli', nome);
            $scope.email = $window.localStorage.setItem('emailCli', email);
            $window.localStorage.setItem('idCli', id);

            console.log('Cliente');

            $state.go('menuCliente');
        }
    }else{
        console.log("Desculpe, mas o navegador nao possui suporte a Web Storage.");
    }

    })
}

}])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Nem a url local não aparece "localhost:8080..."

Comment: Não está conseguindo por quê? Dá algum erro?

Comment: Pq verifico na aba "Application" do console do chrome e não aparece nada em "Local Storage", onde costuma aparecer.

Comment: Tens alguma ideia @jbueno?

Comment: Verifique se não está associando algum valor undefined no localStorage, pois nesse caso ele não salva mesmo.Veja se as variáveis nome, email e id não estão undefined

Comment: Não, @RodolfoJorgeNemerNogueira, nem isso não aparece.

Comment: Tem certeza que tá entrando nos ifs?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta antes de salvar o item no localStorage, transformar ele em String

```
 $window.localStorage.setItem('emailPro', JSON.stringify(email))
```

Depois para recuperar você usa essa função para transformar em um objeto de novo:

```
JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('emailPro'))
```

Comment: Tentarei, valeu.